# ContextMenu Right to Left

Tags: android, menu, contextmenu

I have a contextMenu that It consists of two items Edit and Delete! But because I'm writing my Country language...Items should be Right Align!
Below are my codes. please guide me.Thank!

```
public class ListActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
ListView lst_data;
DicDBAdapter dicDBAdapter;
Dic dic;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);

    lst_data = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lst_data);
    dicDBAdapter = new DicDBAdapter(getApplicationContext());
    ArrayList<String> arrayList = dicDBAdapter.getdata();
    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),
            android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,
            arrayList);
    lst_data.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    registerForContextMenu(lst_data);
}
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.context, menu);


}
```

}
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Create a layout file with a below code.

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    style="?android:attr/dropDownItemStyle"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLargePopupMenu"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:gravity="start"
    android:ellipsize="marquee" />
```

And while creating the array adapter pass this layout as item.

```
ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),
            R.layout.new_layout,
            arrayList);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change layoutDirection in your listView

```
<ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layoutDirection="rtl"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```